# Is there a way to use the mapping GORM 6 "defaultValue" when saving a domain instance

Tags: grails, save, grails-orm, default-value

Suppose I have the following domain class:

```
class DomainClass{

   String field1
   ...
   static mapping = {
      field1 defaultValue: "'Field1'" 
      ...               
   }

}
```

Now I want to save the DomainClass instance using the "defaultValue", in the same way when using a sql insert into a postgresql (INSERT INTO domain_class VALUES(**default**, field2, field3, ...)), e.g.

```
DomainClass dc = new DomainClass()
dc.field1 = "defaultValue"
...
dc.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this...

```
class DomainClass{

    String field1 = "some default value"

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't add a default value constraint in the database.  Unclear if that is your requirement or not.